# Showing only none in output instead of changing numeric value to capitilized alphabets

Tags: python-3.8

def convert_digits(input_string, start_position, end_position):
# The ending index was required as it was not returning the whole sentence
new_string = input_string[:end_position]
newstring = " "
# return new_string

```
digit_mapping = {
    '0': 'ZERO',
    '1': 'ONE',
    '2': 'TWO',
    '3': 'THREE',
    '4': 'FOUR',
    '5': 'FIVE',
    '6': 'SIX',
    '7': 'SEVEN',
    '8': 'EIGHT',
    '9': 'NINE'
}

if start_position >= 1:
    if end_position <= len(new_string):
        if start_position < end_position:
            for index in range(start_position - 1, end_position):
                if input_string[index].isdigit():
                    mapped = digit_mapping[input_string[index]]
                    newstring += " " + mapped + " "

                else:
                    newstring += input_string[index]
        else:
            return "INVALID"

    else:
        return "INVALID"

else:
    return "INVALID"


    return newstring
```

if **name** == '**main**':
print(convert_digits("you are a 4king 5shole", 1, 21))

Answer (score 0):

Use this code.
Your problem was in line 39, you add 2 tabs place 1.

```py
def convert_digits(input_string, start_position, end_position):
    # The ending index was required as it was not returning the whole sentence
    new_string = input_string[:end_position]
    newstring = " "
    # return new_string

    digit_mapping = {
        '0': 'ZERO',
        '1': 'ONE',
        '2': 'TWO',
        '3': 'THREE',
        '4': 'FOUR',
        '5': 'FIVE',
        '6': 'SIX',
        '7': 'SEVEN',
        '8': 'EIGHT',
        '9': 'NINE'
    }

    if start_position >= 1:
        if end_position <= len(new_string):
            if start_position < end_position:
                for index in range(start_position - 1, end_position):
                    if input_string[index].isdigit():
                        mapped = digit_mapping[input_string[index]]
                        newstring += " " + mapped + " "

                    else:
                        newstring += input_string[index]
            else:
                return "INVALID"

        else:
            return "INVALID"

    else:
        return "INVALID"

    return newstring


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(convert_digits("you are a 4king 5shole", 1, 21))
```